# make a blank copy from the existing table

Tags: visual-foxpro, foxpro

How to make a copy with all the structure/schema from an existing table in FoxPro?

```
copy to
```

won't work

Answer (score 4):

There is no single command in VFP, that would copy with everything that an existing table might have. You have to define your requirement and what does your existing table have well.

For example, for simple copy with data you can use:

```
copy to NewTableName with cdx [Database dbName [Name tableNameInNewDb]]
```

This would copy the structure, along with indexes and existing data. However, it wouldn't copy other database level properties if any. You need to use cursorgetprop()\cursorsetprop(), dbgetprop()\dbsetprop() for others.

One way to do a complete copy, is first to get a programmatic version of your database and tables creation using (home()+'tools\gendbc\gendbc.prg') and then edit the generated code for your new table (and also to append the code from the old one).

Wish you initially explained us what do you meant by saying "copy to won't work".

PS: I noticed your question title is saying "make a blank copy". Then you might want to use:

```
copy to NewTableName with cdx for .F.
```

It would copy the structure and indexes but not the data. Other shortcomings still apply. If you didn't need the indexes then a simplier way would be:

```
select * from sourceTable where .F. into table targetTable
```

EDIT: As LAK pointed out, using WHILE instead of FOR would be faster on large tables:

```
copy to NewTableName with cdx while .F.
```

Comment: You'd probably want COPY TO newtable WITH CDX WHILE .F. (not FOR .F., that will take a long time on a table with lots of records - I just tried it on a DBF with 3.8M records, WHILE was instantaneous, FOR took about 10 minutes...).

Comment: COPY STRUCTURE TO newtable CDX works also.  I think I've used this in the past.

Comment: @LAK, then there is something wrong in your table. It shouldn't take 10 minutes or even more than 10 seconds for a mere 3.8 M records (I tested anyway and took 4.7 secs for 3,720,093 records. You are however right using while would be instantaneous (actually I would never want to use COPY TO or COPY STRUCTURE for this. I would instead do that in code as I described - actually I have a utility that creates a table for tables structures and indexes and another that recreates from that information. )

Answer (score 2):

It's

```
copy structure to newfile
```

or, alternatively,

```
copy to newfile for .f.
```

Comment: You'd probably want the CDX clause in order to keep the indices (COPY TO newfile CDX).